# If same value exists in list add it into the new variable

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a list like this

```
month     year  id
1.        2014. 20.
1.        2014. 305.
1.        2014. 305.
```

I would like to create new variable and put into the it all nonunique ids = if is id duplicate, I want to put into the new variable whole row.

```
month     year  id
1.        2014. 305.
1.        2014. 305.
```

Im not sure where to start, I think that I should to create if statement, but I don't know what to put inside it.

```
if(duplicated(my_data$id) = TRUE) {

}
```

Comment: Its not clear to me what your asking, but your statement `if(duplicated(my_data$id) = TRUE)` is not syntactically correct. You might be looking for something like `my_data[duplicated(my_data$id),]` or `my_data[!duplicated(my_data$id),]` or something.

Comment: What is type of your data structure? Is it `data.frame`?

Comment: > typeof(my_data)
[1] "list"

Comment: can you please `dput(my_data)` and share it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to `group_by` `id` and keep all rows where `id` occurs more than once. If so, one approach with `dplyr` might be:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
>   month  year    id
>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1    1. 2014.  305.
> 2    1. 2014.  305.
> ```

And if the structure of your data is a list, I think we can make it a data frame using:

```
# note that you can omit the as.list call assuming your data is already a list
df <- bind_rows(as.list(df))
```

---

Data:

```
Lines <- "month     year  id
          1.        2014. 20.
          1.        2014. 305.
          1.        2014. 305."

df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be achieved using in `base-R` provided the data is in `data.frame`:

```
df$id[df$id %in% df$id[duplicated(df$id)],]

#month year  id
#2     1 2014 305
#3     1 2014 305

#Data

df <-  read.table(text = 
"month     year  id
1.        2014. 20.
1.        2014. 305.
1.        2014. 305.", header = TRUE)
```